# How can I call a function inside a class?

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class in `globals.py` as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class fg():                                                                                                                           
    def red(text):     return f'\033[00;49;031m{text}\033[0m'
    def heading(text): return red(text)
```

and I have the `testrun.py` script as:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from globals import fg

# Command 1:
print(fg.red("My text"))
# prints as expected


# Command 2:
print(fg.heading("My text"))
# throws the error: NameError: name 'red' is not defined
```

The question is how can call `red` function within the `heading` function.

Comment: The real file is actually named something else.
```return fg.red(text)``` works fine.
You said ```this is not how it must be```. I would be grateful if you could tell me the reason. I'm at the very first stage of learning python.

Comment: I delete the comments as there are answers here 'that explain what I said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should have `init` function in a class to call the class, then you should create some functions. Then you can create some static function that can be called without passing the parameters of the Class.
In Your `globals.py` file:

```py
class Fg:
    def __init__(self):
        #You can place some code that you
        #want to call when this class is called
        self.text = ""

    def red(self, text):
        #The self.text will make the text usable by
        # both the functions
        self.text = text

        #Return what ever you want
        return f'\033[00;49;031m{text}\033[0m'

    def heading(self, text):
        self.text = text
        return self.red()
```

In your `testrun.py` file:

```py
from globals import Fg

print(Fg().red("Your Text"))
print(Fg().heighlight("Your Text"))
```

Comment: You should have a `init` class to call the other functions from a function of a class

Comment: Is the line ```self.text = text``` necessary inside the red and heading? Because I commented them out and it's working well.

Comment: It is not so important, but if you define a variable for the class name and use the same name to call both the functions, then I think there might me some problem. If its working, then its okay.

Answer (score 6):

When calling member functions you have to use the self argument, and initiate the class. So the calls would be like this.

```
class fg():                                                                                                                           
    def red(self, text):
        return f'\033[00;49;031m{text}\033[0m'
    def heading(self, text):
        return self.red(text)
```

and then

```
print(fg().red("My text"))
# prints as expected


# Command 2:
print(fg().heading("My text"))
```

Comment: Small correction: `self` is an argument not an attribute. The `self` argument is implicitly added to method calls on classes and is used to access the attributes of an instance.

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a typo in your code. You misspelled return as "retrun".
Also, you can't call a class method directly. Here is what you're probably looking for.

```
class fg():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
    
    def red(self):
        return f'\033[00;49;031m{self.text}\033[0m'

    def heading(self):
        return self.red()
```

And now you can import the file.

```
from globals import fg

obj = fg("My text")
print(obj.red())
print(obj.heading())
```

I have made a lot of modifications to your code.

1. Use self to call the class methods
2. If the text parameter is the same for both, you need not pass it every time you call these methods. Instead, you can initialize that in the self method itself.
3. You first need to create an object of a class to access its methods (called constructors).